# Ravendb Multi Get with index

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-http

I am trying to use ravendb (build 960) multi get to get the results of several queries.

I am posting to /multi_get with:

```
[
  {"Url":"/databases/myDb/indexes/composers?query=title:beethoven&fetch=title&fetch=biography"},
  {"Url":"/databases/myDb/indexes/products?query=title:beethoven&fetch=title&fetch=price"}
]
```

The server responds with results for each query, however it responds with EVERY document for each index. It looks like neither the query is used, or the fetch parameters.

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does it work correctly when you do a regular get for just one of the URLs?  Can you tell us what build of the RavenDB server you are using?  And can you post a small sample of the output?  Thanks.

Comment: The output is a a bit hefty but each query has: {
    "Result": "{\"IdsToInclude\":[],\"Results\":[{... snip ...}] 
"Headers": {
        "Raven-Server-Build": "960",
        "ETag": "78a73e24-1c46-f055-f03f-700a07892105",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Temp-Request-Time": "26 ms"
    },
    "Status": 200
}

Answer (score 1):

Multi GET assumes all the urls are local to the current database, you can specify urls starting with `/datbases/foo`
You specify that in the multi get url.
Change you code to generate:

```
[
  {"Url":"/indexes/composers?query=title:beethoven&fetch=title&fetch=biography"},
  {"Url":"/indexes/products?query=title:beethoven&fetch=title&fetch=price"}
]
```

And make sure that you multi get goes to

```
/databases/mydb/multi_get
```

Comment: This is definetely using the query params now, but it is still not fetching the specified fields. Updated the question to include the build number (960) if that helps (I realise it is old.. on a slow upgrade path)!